# How to install applications to a WebSphere 7.0 cluster using wsadmin?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I want to deploy to all four processes on a Websphere cluster with two nodes. Is there a way of doing this with one Jython command or do I have to call 'AdminControl.invoke' on each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to install an application using wsadmin is with AdminApp and not AdminControl.

I suggest you download [wsadminlib.py](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=166422&filename=wsadminlib.py.zip&method=http&locale=) (Got the link from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html))

it has a lot of functions, one of them is `installApplication` which works also with cluster.

Edit:

Lately I found out about AdminApplication which is a script library included in WAS 7 (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/scriptLibraries/application/V70)

The docuemntation is not great in the info center but its a .py file you can look inside to see what it does.

It is imported automatically to wsadmin and you can use it without any imports or other configuration.

Worth a check.

Comment: As Aviram Segal mentioned AdminApp should be object that is used for Application manipulation (install, uninstall, update etc). Also there isn't a big difference between installing things on a cluster vs a single server.

Answer (score 1):

@aviram-segal is right, [wsadminlib](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html#download) is really helpful for this.
I use the following syntax:

```
    arg = ["-reloadEnabled", "-reloadInterval '0'", "-cell "+self.cellName, "-node "+self.nodeName, "-server '"+ self.serverName+"'", "-appname "+ name, '-MapWebModToVH',[['.*', '.*', self.virtualHost]]]
    AdminApp.install(path, arg)
```

Where path is the location of your EAR/WAR file.
You can find documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_callappinstall.html)